# CakePHP find with LEFT JOIN and generate_series

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, cakephp, generate-series

Basically, is it possible, and if so, how do you do the following code without using the raw query() method in CakePHP 2.0.6. I am using PostgreSQL (which `generate_series()` is a function of). So, how do you do this query the CakePHP way?

```
$sql = "
    SELECT new_rank FROM generate_series(1,999) AS new_rank
    LEFT JOIN tasks ON tasks.rank = new_rank
    WHERE tasks.rank IS NULL LIMIT 1
";
$data = $this->Task->query($sql);
```

**EDIT**
One user said I could try to use the find call on Task and right join to generate_series(). Here is my attempt at that. This code throws an error, in that CakePHP is putting double quotes around the function arguments for generate_series. I wonder how I can get it to not do that?

```
$data = $this->Task->find('all', array(
   'conditions' => array('Task.rank' => null),
   'limit' => 1,
   'recursive' => -1,
   'fields' => 'new_rank',
   'joins' => array(
      array(
          'table'=>'generate_series(1,999)',
          'alias'=>'new_rank',
          'type'=>'RIGHT',
          'conditions' => array(
            'tasks.rank'=>'new_rank'
          )
      )
   )
));
```

Which products the following SQL:

```
SELECT "Task"."new_rank" AS "Task__new_rank"
FROM "tasks" AS "Task"
RIGHT JOIN generate_series("1,999") AS "new_rank" ON ("tasks"."rank" = 'new_rank')
WHERE "Task"."rank" IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any CakePHP but perhaps you can start with Task and RIGHT JOIN to your `generate_series`.

Comment: That is a good idea, and I have updated my OP with my attempt. Unfortunately, ran into a snap where CakePHP puts quotes around 1,999.

Comment: Hmmm, can you specify the `joins` as a raw string? I'm still guessing based on experience with other ORMs.

Comment: Doesn't look like I can. Someone else said that Cake puts the quotes around the function arguments for security reasons.

Comment: Can you use placeholders? Something like `'table' => 'generate_series(?, ?)'` and then supply the 1 and 999 as arguments somewhere?

Comment: Is there a `joins` method of some sort in CakePHP? That might let you join a string without interference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is in `DboSource::expression()`. It basically allows you to do a SQL expression without any of Cake's escaping. Make sure to sanitize inputs.

To have it show up as a field, you can try adding it to the fields key in your options array:

```
$ds = $this->Task->getDataSource();
$this->Task->find('all', array(
  'fields' => $ds->expression('generate_series(1,999) AS new_rank')
));
```

If that doesn't work, you can always try `DboSource::rawQuery()` which doesn't escape *anything*, afaik.

Comment: Although this works for 'fields' it does not for 'table' in the joins parameter. I wish it did work for table. It doesn't look like I can do this strictly Cake, so I'll just keep using Model->query() for now. I am going to give you the credit on this one though for getting me the furthest along.

Comment: It's a shame we couldn't get it to work via the ORM in IRC either. Welp, that's sometimes happens with frameworks :)